# how to add new label in list view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have this **listview** with products that a client will add from another page. Everytime he selects one product, it goes to the **listview**. I managed to make this work, but the listview only shows the first product that the client selected. even to the list have all the products on it.
 What I wanna do is populate the list with the new products added with labels.

this is what i have so far:

```
private void OnProductSelected(object sender, banco_produtos product)
{
    this.produto_selecionado = product;
    var produto_id = product.cod_produto;
    var produto_nome = product.nm_produto;   

    lista.Add(new lista_prod(produto_id, produto_nome));             

    list_view.ItemsSource = lista;         


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lista` should be `ObservableCollection<lista_prod>` or any other equivalent that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. That way, your visual part will be informed on each appropriate change inside the items source.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about **ObservableCollection** :)